# Image Editing Fieldtype (Matrix/Grid compatible)

Tags: matrix, fieldtype, image, editor

I'm looking for a fieldtype that would open a basic image editor with option to Scale + Crop (maintaining proportions as option).

I've reviewed Channel Images which would be OK, but I can't use it in tandem with Playa/Relationships so lose a level of complexity and depth that is very handy for big content sites. I also love how sturdy Matrix is and how quick it is for clients to understand/use.

Is there one knocking about that works inside the control panel, as I'm keen not to have to persuade them that we'll automate it using a tool like CE:img.

Cheers.

Comment: Photo Frame has become a buggy unsupported mess. Don't buy it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Photo Frame](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/photo-frame) from ObjectiveHTML sounds like it would do exactly what you want, and it does support Matrix. It's crazy powerful with an extensible feature set and Justin provides excellent support.